# How to insert value to user entity custom field while creating new account?

Tags: 8, users

I am trying to insert a value into a custom field(`field_custom_referral`) which is created in the backend.When a user creating a account in our application, this particular custom field should be updated with custom value. Can anyone help me out here.

I tried below code in .module file but not working out:

```
function module_user_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity) {
  $entity->set('field_custom_referral', '3');
  $entity->save();
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of your field `field_custom_referral` ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.2.x) in case of entity user expecting `Drupal\user\UserInterface` instance not `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface`

change your hook to:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert().
 */
function MYMODULE_user_insert(Drupal\user\UserInterface $user) {
  $user->set('field_custom_referral', '3');
  $user->save();
}
```